# Принудительный вызов ToolTip

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QLineEdit` с установленным `tooltip`, в которое записываются численные значения. Хочется вызывать `tooltip` у этого поля при некорректном вводе.

Как реализовать подобное, не через `connect`: смотреть корректность ввода —> вызывать искусственно какой-нибудь метод с `mouseEvent`?

**UPD:**
[image: скриншот с реализацией через QToolTip::showText()]

Comment: Можно в лоб вызвать: `QToolTip::showText(line_edit->mapToGlobal(QPoint()), line_edit->toolTip());`. Другой вариант -- послать событие QEvent::ToolTip на нужный виджет

Comment: @gil9red, первый вариант видел, но не понял на счёт QPoint, а именно координат и метода mapToGlobal. Во втором варианте непонятно, в каком виде засылать, через метод `event` у line_edit?

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое, это использование [QToolTip::showText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText):

```
QToolTip::showText(line_edit->mapToGlobal(QPoint()), line_edit->toolTip());
```

[mapToGlobal(QPoint())](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) - возвращает глобальные координаты виджета, от левого верхнего угла.

---

Другой вариант - послать событие [QHelpEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QHelpEvent.html) нужному виджету, используя [QCoreApplication::postEvent](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent)

```
QEvent* event = new QHelpEvent(QEvent::ToolTip, line_edit->pos(), line_edit->mapToGlobal(QPoint()));
QCoreApplication::postEvent(line_edit, event);
```

Comment: Хочется всё-таки через 1-ый вариант, он попроще. Однако всё равно не понятно относительно координат. Если я указываю `QPoint(0,0)`, то тултип появляется, как это показано на виджете. Нулевые координаты относительно левого верхнего угла, как написано в документации. Но тут совсем не так

Comment: Длительность появления можно как-то увеличить? Сделать стандартной что ли.

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov, используйте перегрузку, в которой передается время в миллисекундах: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText-2

Comment: а по поводу координат? Зачем в перегрузке QRect и указатель на QWidget (это на родителя?)?

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov, вы меня так пытаете как будто я это написал :) Зачем-зачем... думаю там перегрузка с большим количеством и ее вызывают все остальные перегрузки, но с указанием пустых значений или nullptr в тех параметрах, чьи значения нет смысла указывать. А по поводу `rect`а там написано: `The rect is in the coordinates of the widget you specify with w. If the rect is not empty you must specify a widget. Otherwise this argument can be 0 but it is used to determine the appropriate screen on multi-head systems.` не стесняйтесь пользоваться переводчиком, если непонятно